# Access syscall error codes

Tags: assembly, shellcode

As part of a shellcoding in linux assembly I created an egghunter shellcode that uses the Access syscall to find the shellcode in memory and execute it. This worked perfectly on a ubuntu 12.04 VM, but when using it on my "normal" ubuntu 18.04 it does not work.

It is based upon the fact that the access syscall should return an EFAULT error when not being able to access a part of memory. This would normally return 0x2f to the al register (rax is set to 0xfff......2f). This worked on the ubuntu VM, but on my normal machine it return a 0xea (rax is set to 0xfff....ea).

I am assuming this is another error and if I know what error this is I should be able to fix my shellcode. But I cannot find what it stands for. I read the unistd.h and associate files, but found nothing.

Comment: `0xffffffea` is -22 aka `-EINVAL`. This is set when `mode` is invalid. You can check this out in the manual (section 2, entry `access`) or directly in the kernel code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/fs/open.c#L353) (`access` forwards to `faccessat`).

Comment: Ah, thanks! Just so that I learn how to debug these things myself: when you say I can check it out in the manual section 2 entry access where do I look for this? I am quite a newby in this, just a pentester learning some more basic coding for antivirus evasion and shellcoding :D (and can you make this an answer instead of comment then I can accept it)

Comment: @Wealot Type `man 2 access` to get the manual page for `access` in chapter 2 (system calls).

Comment: Ok top thanks! And how did you know -22 is EINVAL? Where can I find this information normally? (again sorry for the noobish questions)

Comment: That is inside `errno.h` either directly or in some nested include file.

Comment: Run your code under `strace` to decode system call args / return values.  e.g. `strace ./a.out`.  And BTW, the full range of possible error codes is `-1..-4095` (so `mmap` can return any possible aligned page address).  But most of that range is unused, so checking only `al` might be valid.

Comment: For the exercise just al is valid :D. Thanks for all the replies! I'm getting more and more understanding of how the base of it all works :D. Margaret please put your comment as answer (maybe with the text of the other comments with it for extra information?) and I'll accept it. Thanks again all!